# Terraform - How to output multiple value

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am very new to Terraform, and programming, however, I have to develop my skills, so I would appreciate your suggestion to have the correct output.tf file.

**In my main.tf, I wrote**:

```
terraform {

  required_version = ">=0.12"
  
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>2.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "RG1" {
  name      = "AZ-VNET"
  location  = var.resource_group_location
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "RG2" {
  name      = "AZ-Migrate"
  location  = var.resource_group_location
}
```

**In my output.tf I wrote:**

```
output "resource_group_name" {
    value = azurerm_resource_group.RG*.name
   
}
```

The result is not printing both Resource Groups names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have multiple resources in a single output, but to make it work, you need to use some terraform function, or format the output depending on the type, if it is a list, string, map.. When you have a chance, take a look on https://www.terraform.io/language/functions -- I'll show an example that you will have a list of the ids.

1 - By the way, we can't use * in a string like a wildcard, the * is used mostly when we are working with modules, or dynamic resources or your resources that outputs a list, but in any case, putting a * in the resource name will not work. We use `*`  before the attribute from a resource, let's say we have a module that creates an `ABC` resource and this resource has an `id` attribute. It would be `module.ABC.*.id`- but it doesn't work for everything, you need to know what's the type of the output, if it is a string, a list, a map as I said.

3 - I don't work with Azure, but If you go to the doc of that resource on https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_group -- You can see the only exported attribute from this resource is `id`. Given that, you can do something like:

```
output "resource_group_name" {
  value = [azurerm_resource_group.RG1.id, azurerm_resource_group.RG2.id]
}
```

Now let's say you really need to output the name of these resources, you can create `locals` block to define the name of the resources, and then you will be able to export them querying the `locals` values, like:

```
locals {
  azurerm_resource_group_rg1 = "AZ-VNET"
  azurerm_resource_group_rg2  = "AZ-Migrate"
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "RG1" {
  name      = local.azurerm_resource_group_rg1
  location  = var.resource_group_location
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "RG2" {
  name      = local.azurerm_resource_group_rg2
  location  = var.resource_group_location
}
```

And an output with:

```
output "resource_group_name" {
  value = [local.azurerm_resource_group_rg1, local.azurerm_resource_group_rg2]
}
```

But don't do that now, I don't know if they would be recreated, I don't know these resources. Just do this if you are good with this.

Let me know if you got it.

Comment: Thanks Juan, your response solved my requirements, you are really awesome

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Let me know if you need something else!

Answer (score -1):

You can also try this :

```
output"resource_group_name{value=azurerm_resource_group.RG*.access_ip
```

}